# What would be the most scalable/extensible way to design an error messaging system for an application? I will be using Perl.

Tags: perl, error-handling, architecture

I just need a general architecture for this design. Currently I am thinking of creating a script with a hash of all the error messages. The error messages themselves are also hashes containing status codes and the error messages in the application. Then where the error occurs in the code of the application I just have the die function which creates a new error and uses the name of the error from the script containing the list of errors. I don't know if this is the best or most efficient way to design such a system. I am trying to design it in such a way so that if more errors have to be added. Any ideas or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say;

*The error messages themselves are also hashes containing status codes and the error messages in the application. Then where the error occurs in the code of the application I just have the die function which creates a new error and uses the name of the error from the script containing the list of errors.*

... you, more or less, are describing exception objects.  This simple exception class [(taken from here)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExceptionHandlingInPerl)

```
package Exception;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    bless { msg=>"@_" }, $class;
}

sub what
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    return sprintf "Exception: %s\n", $self->{msg};
}
```

accomplishes a lot for its size and is used like this;

```
sub try(&)   { eval {$_[0]->()}  }
sub throw($) { die $_[0]         }
sub catch(&) { $_[0]->($@) if $@ }

# The main program
try {
    throw Exception->new("A real exception");
};
catch {
    print $@->what;
};
```

This object has only one attribute, **msg** (called as **->what**), but you could obviously have attributes for error codes, apps, app phases and so on.  Notice that `&throw` is a small wrapper around **die** and the exception object is created at the spot its need - much like your statement *"... where the error occurs in the code of the application I just have the die function which creates a new error..."*

Your *"script with a hash of all the error messages"* then becomes a (sub) module of your app dedicated to exception objects which either

1) pre-creates them all and indexes them by some error code; or

2) (better) creates a small hierarchy of general to
    increasingly specific exception classes from which you likewise create on-the-fly exception objects as errors are detected (much like the above)

Finally, depending on your circumstances, you may want to go with a pre-canned, full-bells-and-whistles solution from cpan. I haven't used it myself but [Exception::System](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::System) looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Base) is excellent.

> This class implements a fully OO exception mechanism similar to `Exception::Class` or `Class::Throwable`. It provides a simple interface allowing programmers to declare exception classes. These classes can be thrown and caught. Each uncaught exception prints full stack trace if the default verbosity is increased for debugging purposes.
>
> The features of `Exception::Base`:
>
> - fast implementation of the exception class
> - fully OO without closures and source code filtering
> - does not mess with `$SIG{__DIE__}` and `$SIG{__WARN__}`
> - no external run-time modules dependencies, requires core Perl modules only
> - the default behavior of exception class can be changed globally or just for the thrown exception
> - matching the exception by class, message or other attributes
> - matching with string, regex or closure function
> - creating automatically the derived exception classes ("use" in perlfunc interface)
> - easily expendable, see `Exception::System` class for example
> - prints just an error message or dumps full stack trace
> - can propagate (rethrow) an exception
> - can ignore some packages for stack trace output
> - some defaults (i.e. verbosity) can be different for different exceptions